# Logical and alphabetological variant?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic

The notion of *alphabetical variant* is well known, so that a formula $x=x$ is an alphabetical variant of $y=y$ if $x$ and $y$ are distinct variables.

One may want to consider the set term $\{x:x \neq x \wedge A \}$ a *logical variant* of $\{x:x \neq x \}$ if $A$ is a tautology of predicate logic. Given such notions of alphabetical and logical variants, one may consider $\{x:x \neq x \wedge A \}$ an *alphabetological* variant of $\{y:y \neq y\}$.

Do my notions of *logical variant* and *alphabetological variant* have provenances?

Comment: For what it's worth, Takeuti's proof theory (2nd ed. 1987) refers to 'alphabetical variants' in p. 18 def 2.15 with reference to substitutions of bound variables only (so $x=x$ and $y=y$ are not alphabetical variants when $x\neq y$ according to this definition).

Comment: However, the formulas $\forall x((x\in z)\leftrightarrow(x = x))$ and $\forall y((y\in z)\leftrightarrow(y = y))$ are $\alpha$-equivalent for all $z\not\in\{x,y\}$, which is probably the notion you want to refer to (as Takeuti) under the label 'alphabetical variant'. As for 'logical variant', i have the feeling you are asking for the provenance of the so-called 'Lindenbaum-Tarski congruence' $\Gamma\vdash (\phi\leftrightarrow\psi)$

Comment: Thanks, Noel. That leaves only the alphabetological variant, it seems.

Comment: Can you confirm you are referring to the notion of $\alpha$-equivalence as per [this](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/alpha-equivalence)? If so, I would be surprised if the idea did not originate from Russell or Frege. If not, I am not familiar with your notion.

Comment: I don't think that "alphabetological variant" is a good term, because it would suggest the notion of a variant in the sense of alphabetology (which seems to be a real word for the study or science of alphabets.)

Comment: I see. However, the context of my use of the term would not be likely to be confused with the science of alphabets. So I will consider whether I find a good replacement, and if not perhaps I use $alphabetological$ despite its somewhat esoteric prior use.

Comment: In fact, for the same reason as it was suggested a problem with my chosen terminology that $alphabetology$ was a taken term, it may be taken as an advantage. For the distinction I want to make is one which pertains to the science of alphabets, as it were - in logic and mathematics; i.e. the term $alphabetological \ variant$ so taken is an alphabetological term.

Comment: Noel: I can confirm that the notion of $\alpha$-equivalence is appropriate for what I was calling $alphabetical \ variant$. I would share your surprise if neither Frege nor Russell were on to this. But it would be interesting to know the details. Perhaps even earlier authors partly originated the language use?

Comment: Please use `*italics*` or `**bold**` instead of `$math$` to emphasize text.